# Android studio file path directory is not created

Tags: android, android-studio

I tried to use this code for creating a directory for my picture file

```
File pictureFileDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM),"MyApp");
        Log.v("Log","Reaching position 1");
        if (!pictureFileDir.exists()) {
            boolean isDirectoryCreated = pictureFileDir.mkdirs();
            if(!isDirectoryCreated)
                Log.i("TAG", "Can't create directory to save the image");
            return null;
        }
```

But in return I get Log tag `Log.i("TAG", "Can't create directory to save the image");` which means my directory is not created. I know the method `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()` is deprecated, but it should work with my marshmellow version. But not working.

I also try another code here as a solution to deprecated:

```
ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, "AppPic");
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);

        Uri uri = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues);

        File pictureFileDir = new File(String.valueOf(uri));
        Log.v("Log","Reaching position 1");
        if (!pictureFileDir.exists()) {
            boolean isDirectoryCreated = pictureFileDir.mkdirs();
            if(!isDirectoryCreated)
                Log.i("TAG", "Can't create directory to save the image");
            return null;
        }
```

But it's giving me error of `java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: writing com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider`. I took permission of:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

What should I do?

Comment: Are you asking for runtime permissions?

Comment: @TaseerAhmad Yes I have taken care of the ContentResolver problem by taking runtime permission. But now it acts like the first problem. I am having a log tag of Log.i("TAG", "Can't create directory to save the image");

Comment: Have you created FileProvider.xml and register in manifest ?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I can not add comment.
I used your code then I got

```
pictureFileDir.getAbsolutePath() = null
```

Please check it again.